# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico]

Tags: spring-mvc

I can't recall what I have changed on my code but whenever I click on any links on my web it gives me this :

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

A portion of my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

some configuration of my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- testing for pdf export -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml" />
        <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Other than that everything works fine, means any page is loaded correctly without any error. May I know what might cause this ? And who is using that .ico image ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most web browsers attempt to fetch a site's [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) at the root of the context with a request for the `/favicon.ico` resource *automatically*. In your case is not handled by any configured Spring mapping.

If you have a favicon at `/favicon.ico` or in another location you could configure a mapping in Spring to resolve the request to a valid resource:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `favicon.ico` : icon in the browser tab

Since Spring Security are using

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Did you exclude the `favicon.ico` from filtering by Spring Security?

```
<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate favicon.ico in your html page as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link href="[YOUR_FAVICON_PATH]/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
</html>
```