# No favicon.ico for a simple Spring - Maven Web Application

Tags: java, spring, favicon

I am learning Spring Java Framework, but have the problem with the favicon. I want to get ordinary favicon in the simplest way. I placed the `favicon.ico` file like this `src/main/resources/static/favicon.ico`, also tried in just `resources` folder.

When I did a deployment to a remote GlassFish 5.1 web server the error happened:

`[2020-07-18T02:45:52.695+0200] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] [tid: _ThreadID=696 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1595033152695] [levelValue: 900] [[ No mapping for GET /favicon.ico]]`

And no favicon was present on a website.

At the remote the favicon can be found at this location:
`./glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/HelloSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/static/favicon.ico`

Here you are my files

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ga.rekano</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloSpring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Config.java**

```
package app;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("app")
public class Config extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{Config.class};
    }
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**Hello.java**

```
package app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Hello {
    @GetMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Spring";
    }
}
```

How to get favicon visible?

**edit**
My question is related to the configuration without files web.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml so the answers for questions where these files exist don't solve my problem. I have the very simple application that works and I believe that it is not necessary to add special xml files just to add the favicon. But of course I am a newbie so can be wrong. But on the other hand it is very strange because there are some tutorials where the problem looks like very simple: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon
So the question could be why this simplest method doesn't work in my case?

Comment: A very similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036400/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-favicon-ico

You may try adding an mvc:resource mapping as shown in that solution.

Comment: Where should I place this: `<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" />` that is mentioned in the answer?
`

Comment: Should be spring-web-config.xml, I would start small and follow some guide where you can play with the code: 
https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: @Boris That configuration is entirely obsolete with Spring Boot.

Comment: This should work. Is there a specific reason you're using `war` style (which is the more difficult way, and not recommended for new projects)?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- OP did not specify they were using Boot, just Spring. Yes it is easier with Spring Boot as it auto-configures many things. Though I think there is value in understanding how it was done in traditional Spring - this will give the developer an appreciation for how much weight Spring Boot lifts!

Comment: @Boris If OP is "learning Spring", then OP _should_ be using Boot rather than getting lost in the details that I haven't needed professionally in 6 years before understanding how the pieces fit together generally.